# C# Reflection Help? (GetProperties)

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

My code is returning a blank array of PropertyInfo

```
PropertyInfo[] classProperties = typeof(Processor).GetProperties();
```

All properties in this class are public.
Using .NET 2.0 Framework.

I have also tried using an instance declared earlier in my code:

```
PropertyInfo[] classProperties = Computer.Processor[0].GetType().GetProperties();
```

And I have tried using bindings such as Default, Instance and Public.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post of the code of the `Processor` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameterless form will return public properties. So there are 2 likely options:

- they are not properties (but instead, fields)
- they are not public

A public property is something a: with the `public` modifier, and b: with a `get` or `set` accessor, for example either of:

```
public int Foo {get;set;} // automatically implemented property
public string bar;
public string Bar { // manually implemented property
    get { return bar; }
    set { bar = value; }
}
```

Note also that interface-bound properties that are implemented as explicit interface implementation will only be reflected if you query against the interface, not the class; so the following will not show unless you start from `typeof(ISomeInterface)`:

```
string ISomeInterface.Bar { get { return someValue; } }
```

Comment: You're dead right - what I needed was GetFields() rather than GetProperties().

Comment: @CJxD actually, I would say tht what you need is: to change your class to expose properties instead of fields. Public fields are in almost all cases a bad idea.

Comment: Because I have an immense number of fields with starting values, and these fields will never contain information that the user shouldn't be able to transform or view, I opted for public fields to reduce spaghetti code. Why not?

Comment: @CJxD because most data-binding and abstractions work at the property level, and it is a breaking change in the cases of BinaryFormatter, or any code mutating a struct or using "ref" semantics, so can be a pain to add later. Plus adding `{get;set;}` is hardly spaghetti